# Ehad Mi Yodea on the mishnayos

Tags: number, passover, passover-seder-hagada, mishna

I have an idea to compile a song for the Passover Seder. It is based on the famous "Ehad Mi Yodea", but the answers to the question should be mishnayos mentioning the number. The intention is to make some fun at the end of the seder, when everyone is already pretty tired.

So far I've finished the most of the song but I'm still missing something. Here is what I have:

```
אחד מי יודע, אחד אני יודע: באחד באדר משמיעין על השקלים
(שקלים, פ"א, מ"א)

שתים מי יודע, שתים אני יודע: שני דייני גזילות היו בירושלם
(כתובות, פי”ג, מ"א)

שלוש מי יודע, שלוש אני יודע: על שלושה דברים העולם עומד
(אבות, פ"א, מ"ב)

ארבעה מי יודע, ארבעה אני יודע: ארבעה אבות נזיקין
(ב"ק, פ"א, מ"א)

חמישה מי יודע, חמישה אני יודע: חמישה טבילות טובל כהן גדול ומקדש בו ביום
(יומא, פ"ג, מ"ג)

שישה מי יודע, שישה אני יודע:להשלים

שבעה מי יודע, שבעה אני יודע: בשבע דרכים בודקין את הזב
(זבין פ"ב מ"ב)

שמונה מי יודע, שמונה אני יודע: שמונה שרצים האמורים בתורה
(שבת, פי"ד, מ"א)

תשעה מי יודע, תשעה אני יודע: תשע נערות נדריהן קיימין
(נדרים, פי"א, מ"י)

עשרה מי יודע, עשרה אני יודע: עשרה יוחסין עלו מבבל 
(קידושין, פ"ד, מ"א)

אחד עשרה מי יודע, אחד עשרה אני יודע: להשלים

שנים עשר מי יודע, שנים עשר אני יודע: להשלים

שלושה עשר מי יודע, שלושה עשר אני יודע: שלוש עשרה שופרות היו במקדש
(שקלים, פ"ו, מ"א)
```

So I'm missing 6,11 and 12. 
I know that there are mishnayos that describe sacrifices where I can find those number, or in the begging of the "Megila" there are 11,12 and so on.
But those are not in the "tone" of the rest of the song. I'd like to find those number with respect to a list of distinguishable objects not as a date or number of animals to sacrifice. I'm not happy with the "1" also, but that is what I have for a while.

So, if you know good places in mishnayos where missing numbers are mentioned or do you have better ideas to the numbers already listed above, you are welcomed to contribute.

P.S. It is really hard for me to translate those mishnayos to English, so I apologize if someone can't catch the idea of the question.

---

***Edit***

Thanks to all for input.
To those who is interested, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnw0frqvmu5q69n/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97.odt)  is the final version of the song.
I preferred to select first mishnayos of a perek, because this is usually the name of the perek, so the numbers would be easier recognizable.

Comment: Primarily opinion based?

Comment: This song has already been written http://zemer.co.il/song.asp?id=2399 and you can find it on YouTube

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes. However, there's no "12" (on the page you linked to, anyway).

Comment: For 11, how about *Sanhedrin* (5:5): אחד עשר מזכין ואחד עשר מחייבין ואחד אומר איני יודע... יוסיפו הדיינין. Or *Middos* (4:7): והאולם אחד עשר.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F

Comment: @DoubleAA wow, didn't knew someone already tried this. Anyway, there are some problems with that song. For example "Ehad hofer bor" is not about numbers, also there is no 12 (like msh210 said) and no 13.

Comment: @Fred those are not 11 "distinguishable objects", just counting number of mezakin. Also in Middos, it's just the length of something, not counting objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mikvaos 1:1 - שש מעלות במקואות.

Also, Zevachim 4:6 - לשם ששה דברים הזבח נזבח.

Also, Middos 5:3 - שש לשכות היו בעזרה.

Kesuvos 5:2 - נותנים לבתולה שנים עשר חודש משתבעה הבעל.

Also, Menachos 6:5 - חוץ מלחם הפנים וחביתי כוהן גדול, שהן באות שתים עשרה, דברי רבי יהודה; רבי מאיר אומר, כולן באות שתים עשרה--חוץ מחלות תודה והנזירות, שהן באות עשר עשר.

Comment: +1 for the _Mikva'os_ source. I think that satisfies the criteria of the question.

Comment: Yes, the Mikvaos is perfect. About 12 - it not satisfies the question criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Mechon Mamre searching makes this easier. It looks like 11 hasn't been filled in yet, so here are a few options:

Niddah 4:7 --
כל אחד עשר יום, בחזקת טהרה.

Niddah 5:6 --
בת אחת עשרה שנה ויום אחד, נדריה נבדקין

Middot 2:6 --
עזרת ישראל הייתה אורך מאה ושלושים וחמש, על רוחב אחת עשרה

My personal favorite, considering the name of the song:

Sanhedrin 5:5 --
אחד עשר מזכין ואחד עשר מחייבין, ואחד אומר איני יודע

Answer (score 2):

### 6

Rosh Hashana 1:3 - על שישה חודשים שלוחים יוצאים

Eiduyot 5:1 - שישה דברים מקולי בית שמאי, ומחומרי בית הלל

Taharot 4:5 - על שישה ספקות, שורפין את התרומה

### 11

Brachot 7:3 - אחד עשרה, ואחד עשר ריבוא ?? (tried)

### 12

Horiot 1:6 - שנים עשר שבטים מביאין שנים עשר פרים

Keilim 29:3 - חוט משקולת, שנים עשר

Answer (score 1):

What about Pesachim 4:8 ששה דברים עשו אנשי יריחו, על שלשה מחו בידם, ועל שלשה לא מחו בידם.

ואלו הן שלא מחו בידם, מרכיבין דקלים כל היום, וכורכין את שמע, וקוצרין יז וגודשין לפני העמר יח, ולא מחו בידם.

ואלו שמחו בידם, מתירין גמזיות של הקדש, ואוכלין מתחת הנשרים בשבת, ונותנין פאה לירק, ומחו בידם חכמים

or the next Mishna 4:9

ששה דברים עשה חזקיה המלך, על שלשה הודו לו, ועל שלשה לא הודו לו.

גרר עצמות אביו כ על מטה של חבלים, והודו לו.

כתת נחש הנחשת, והודו לו.

גנז ספר רפואות, והודו לו.

על שלשה לא הודו לו, קצץ דלתות של היכל ושגרן למלך אשור, ולא הודו לו כג.

סתם מי גיחון כד העליון, ולא הודו לו.

עבר ניסן בניסן, ולא הודו לו

Answer (score 0):

Not quite mishnayot, but a baraita from masekhet Sofrim (19:10) for 12:

וכשהוא מקלסו מקלסו בשנים עשר טובי העיר כנגד שנים עשר שבטים ושנים עשר חבירים ושני' עשר חדשים ושנים עשר מזלות

and from Avot de Rabbi Natan (34:5) for 11:

אחת עשרה היא והיא כתיב ביו"ד בתורה

Answer (score 0):

12:
בבא מציעא 
ד,ו
אם היה מכירה, אפילו לאחר שנים עשר חודש מקבלה הימנו

13:
 תענית 
 א,ו
שלוש עשרה תענייות על הציבור